# jquery autocomplete from file with json and first character match

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have a text file which contain names in simple json format (without headers):
[ "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", (...)]

My html page with autocomplete input form have this jquery script:

```
var tags = "\path\to\jsontxtfile.txt";

$( "#id_name" ).autocomplete({ 
source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
        response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
            return matcher.test( item );
        }) );
    }
});
```

When i use normal autocomplete i just put the path to my file in source without a function (source: "\path\to\jsontxtfile.txt") and it's working great , but when i try to use only first letter match from jquery autocomplete documentation it's not working. I don't know what to place in tags variable. In documentation they used hardcoded tags variable (like var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];) but i have a file with like 1600+ names and i don't want to put it inside my html code like they suggest.

Comment: please elaborate on what do you mean by `when i use normal autocomplete` also tell us what error do you see ? do you see the function sending a request on the first keyup ?

Comment: by normal autocomplete i mean wihtout RegExp function, I just place path to text file in autocomplete source parameter. And i don't receive any errors (via Firebug). I think it just reading the string in tags variable ... not the file inside. When i use aoutocomplete it only show letters inside string var "tags", not the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never retrieves the file from server. `var tags` is just a string that represents the path. But you are trying to parse `tags` as if it is the array of data included in that file

One very simple solution is to include the file in a script tag in your page

```
<script src="\path\to\jsontxtfile.txt"></script>
```

This would require you to actually create a variable in the file to define the array it contains. At very beginning of file add `var tags=`

Once it is included you can access the array`tags` in your code.

You can also use AJAX to retrieve the file if this is not a viable solution:

```
/* retrieve file*/
$.getJSON("\path\to\jsontxtfile.txt", function(tags) {
    /* data now available, initialize autocomplete*/
    $("#id_name").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
                return matcher.test(item);
            }));
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: i'am complete newbie... if i place this script tag, what should i place in var tags = ? how do i refer to this script src ?

Comment: `var tags` would be in the file already. You would delete the line you have that has `var tags=` in it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `minChars` option of jQuery Autocomplete plugin. Try the following

```
var tags = "\path\to\jsontxtfile.txt";

$( "#id_name" ).autocomplete({ 
minChars: 1,
source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
        response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
            return matcher.test( item );
        }) );
    }
});
```

You can read more about how to use autocomplete and it's options [here.](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#how-to-use)

## update

you can write a method to create an array from the text file:

```
function get_suggestions(){
    $.get("/path/to/jsontxtfile.txt", { }, function(data){
        var data_array = eval(data);
        data_array = data;
    });
}
```

and then use it as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var autocomplete_opts = get_suggestions();
    $( "#id_name" ).autocomplete({ minChars: 1, source: autocmplete_opts});
});
```